# Rake aborted on multiple machines. CompilationError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, passenger

I've had this problem with my Rails application for a long time now. I finally have the time to mess with it but I don't understand what the problem is. Within Phusion Passenger I get this error, on my Ubuntu server I get this error, and now at Heroku I still see this error.

I've logged in to Heroku in Terminal with `heroku login`, then I run the rake command: `heroku run rake db:version --app tara-crammer-designs`.

This is where I see that error:

```
Running `rake db:version` attached to terminal... up, run.4434
/app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.2.0/Inline_FastImage_bbac2b6030874ea47494fd3952895412.c:2:16: fatal error: gd.h: No such file or directory
 #include "gd.h"
                ^
compilation terminated.
rake aborted!
CompilationError: error executing "gcc -shared   -fPIC  -O3 -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -L. -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -I /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/include/ruby-2.2.0/x86_64-linux -I /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/include -L/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.2/lib -o \"/app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.2.0/Inline_FastImage_bbac2b6030874ea47494fd3952895412.so\" \"/app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.2.0/Inline_FastImage_bbac2b6030874ea47494fd3952895412.c\" -lgd ": pid 6 exit 1
Renamed /app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.2.0/Inline_FastImage_bbac2b6030874ea47494fd3952895412.c to /app/.ruby_inline/ruby-2.2.0/Inline_FastImage_bbac2b6030874ea47494fd3952895412.c.bad
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:618:in `build'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/RubyInline-3.12.4/lib/inline.rb:856:in `inline'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastimage_resize-2.0.3/lib/fastimage_resize.rb:116:in `<class:FastImage>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/fastimage_resize-2.0.3/lib/fastimage_resize.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

What does this mean? How do I fix this and run my migrations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like one of your gems (`fastimage_inline`) requires native library `libgd`, but heroku does not provide it. First link from google for 'libgd heroku' might be helpful: http://www.developwith.com/how-do-i/ruby/add-image-processing-heroku-buildpack.html

Comment: I removed it (I looked up how to completely get rid of it because it was apparently still around random parts of my filesystem although I'd thought I had deleted it) and all is good now! Thank you! :D